# Best way to display pages

Tags: php, html

Which one of these is better :

```
include("up.php");
content here
include("down.php");
```

up.php file contains each page up part
down.php file contains each page footer part

or

```
$sivu = $_GET['sivu'];
$sivu = str_replace("/", "", $sivu); //only this directory allowed
include("".$sivu.".php");
```

Comment: How to compare two way that is not doing the same thing?

Comment: they are not doing same thing in server side, but same thing in user side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first solution is easy to read, easy to debug, and perfectly safe, even on Windows.

The second solution allows attackers to execute arbitrary files, at least on Windows by using backslashes(`\`) instead of slashes. Also, it's unnecessarily complex.